# which is better for implementing median of medians algorithm - ArrayList or Linkedlist?

Tags: java

I am trying to implement the median of medians algorithm in Java.
I was wondering which of these two list implementations would cost less in terms of list traversal and comparison?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried implementing the algorithm with both kinds of list and then measuring the performance?

Answer (score 1):

An `ArrayList` should be slightly more efficient because the algorithm needs some random access to the data structure that takes O(1) for the `ArrayList` and O(n) for the `LinkedList`.

`LinkedList` is more efficient for remove operations (O(1) for `LinkedList` and O(n) for `ArrayList`), but this should not be the case in your algorithm.